# Enviar y recibir parametro por medio url - Django

Tags: django, django-urls

Tengo esta template detalle torneo , necesito enviar como parametro el id del torneo ya que al crear equipo tiene una relacion directa al torneo que participa. Como envio y recibo en el template equipo_crear el id del torneo.

## torneo_detalle.html

```
    <h5><a href="{% url 'torneos:equipo_crear' object.id%}">Agregar Equipo</a></h5>
```

## urls.py

```
    url(r'^detalle/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', login_required(Torneo_DetailView.as_view()), name='torneo_detalle'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/equipo/$', login_required(Equipo_CreateView.as_view()), name='equipo_crear'),
```

Comment: Nunca pude hacerlo de estas maneras, investigue bastante. Logre hacerlo asignandole action al form donde ubicaba la entrada del dato (select, listas, input, etc.) y luego pasarlo por get al view.

Answer (score 3):

```
{% url 'torneos:equipo_crear' pk=object.id %}
```

El parámetro "pk" se pide por nombre, posiblemente funcione el enviar el valor por nombre.

Comment: Ok disculpen soy algo nuevo en esto, edité mi comentario porque creo está más correcto el código de está manera.

Comment: Para agregar código, luego de pegarlo, se debe selecionar completamente y hacer click en el botón `{  }` (o Ctrl + K)

Comment: Al contrario, gracias por aportar contenido. Sólo es la intención de ayudarte en los primeros pasos (sé que puede costar un poco al principio)

Comment: y como atrapo el valor id en la otra template equipo_crear.html ?

Comment: Se recibe en la vista, en los parametros. Por ejemplo:

def vista(request, id = None):
    ...

Comment: En el caso que sea una vista basada en clase ?

Comment: @jhonperez me parece que con esta respuesta ya queda contestada esta pregunta, si tienes otra duda por favor abre otra pregunta